# Magento 2 : Category products dynamic rules get scope between 10% and 20% discount

Tags: discount, rules, scope, dynamic

We have a category where we need to add all products from another category with between 10% and 20% discount. The problem is that some of the products have a special price AND a price-rule which overrule the special price.

Let say we have a cup with a price of 100$ and a special price of 80$ the discount is 20% but the products have an applied price rule which gives a 30% discount on the price.

The cup should appear on our 30% category and not the 20% category. How do we do that?